# different number of results in SQL Statement when using die()

Tags: php, mysql

In a PHP script I do a MySQL Request where `$SQL` is a hardcoded SQL-SELECT statement:

```
$Result = mysqli_query($server,$SQL);
echo '<br>'.$SQL.'*'.mysqli_num_rows($Result);
#die('test');
```

The whole script is quite complex but running the code above prints the SQL-Statement and delivers **14 Result rows**.
As I wanted to check the database directly at this point I added the above `die()` after the request. But doing so the SQL-satement now is delivering just **13 Result rows**.

I know that cutting the code after the execution may change the state of the system as probable database operations in the cut off code won't come into effect anymore. But no matter if in the run before the `die()` has been active or not I always get 14 Results without a `die()` and always 13 Results with a `die()`.

So my problem is: **everytime** when I run the code without the `die()` and  and directly afterwards run the code again with the `die()` activated then until the `die()` statement there is no obvious difference in the code or the state of the database so the SELECT statement should always deliver the same number of rows... which it doesn't.

**Can anyone think of a setting which makes this behavior understandable?** I hope my explanation is not to wierd - otherwise I am happy to answer any questions. There is obviously a simple explanation which only I seem to miss...

**Edit:**

The problem I have is probably a bug I have hidden in a large piece of code. This surely is hard to answer especially if you have not got the full code. But maybe it helps if I reformulate my question to the following task:

> Can you program a PHP code including the above snippet which shows the same behavior - so after each run (activated or not) it always delivers 14 Results with the die() deactivated and 13 runs with the die() activated? - of course allowing the sourcecode to analyze itself would be cheating...

**Edit 2:**

**I found the reason of the Error.** It is because the printing of PHP notices and warning in the code which accumulated during development and which in Firefox seem to lead to a problem if they reach a certain size before the `<head>` section. The `die()` case causes less of these because it breaks earlier and in fact doesn't even reach the `<head>`. If I mute notices both examples behave the same. What exactly lead to the error then I haven't examined... Sorry that I did not hint the error reporting in describing my question, but I had no clue that that might be the reason - especially as it was active in both cases....

Comment: The 14th result is an output that comes from a line after the die?

Comment: there's no way that the presence/absence of `die()` in php AFTER you run the query could affect how many rows are in the db.

Comment: @Blaatpraat but he uses `mysqli_num_rows` to count rows, so it doesn't matter if there is content after the die... unwanted output would be in the `$Result`... :S

Comment: @Blaatpraat: It comes from the mysqli_num_rows($Result) of the same echo-line

Comment: @Marc B: The die() changes the database because certain operations are cut off. But when I make a run without the die() the starting situation for the next run is the same again. But in this next run the number of results seems to depent whether the die() is set there...

Comment: then what's the problem? Exactly how do you expect us to help if you don't show what these other "operations" are? we can NOT help you with anything you don't show us...

Comment: @Marc B: I know it is a bit vague, but the whole code seems too complex to post here. **But after a run the database has a defined condition. So when I start the next run until the die() the exacly same should happen.** Nevertheless I can "decide" to get 14 Results or 13 Results by adding the die() ...

Comment: The behaviour is nothing to do with the `die()` statement, it's the code before/after. Try creating a test script simply connecting to the DB then running your snippet and nothing else. Check your results with and without the `die()` statement then report back.

Comment: Do you use buffered or unbuffered queries? Have you tried a smaller, self-contained example that focuses exclusively on that problem? Does it exhibit the same result, i.e. can you reproduce the problem? If yes, can you please provide that self-contained example script, the table definition and sample data (preferably in the form of valid `CREATE TABLE ...` and `INSERT INTO ...` statements)?

Comment: @Wee Zel: of course then the result is the same and there is no problem, the problem is in the code. But I can not think of a reason why the same code with the same start settings behaves predictably different. The code is the same, the database at codestart is the same. I can run the code again and again getting 14 results. But the moment I add the die() I have only 13 ... I cant' think of any reason - or to say it in other words: can you write me a code with a select statement which delivers predictably different results when adding a die() after it....

Comment: Wooz, honestly we get it `die()`/not `die()`, 13/14.

Comment: if you can't post the code then you're on your own. I suggest that you try isolating where this changes between 13 and 14. move your "debug" lines around, what does it return at the top of the code? what does it return at the bottom? and various points in between? - it's gonna be a long haul, good luck buddy

Comment: @VolkerK: I read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.html - as I understand my queries are buffered. The problem is reproduceable. I could try to send a reduced code along with an SQL-dump. As this will be some work for me (and for the recipient): would anyone read it and where would I upload it?

Comment: Well, if it's just one query on one table and straight forward reproducible I guess it should be 30, 40 lines of code/statements? That would fit nicely in the question text above. The goal would be to make it as simple as possible for the reciepient - and for yourself when debugging the thing. "no, that's too simple, it doesn't happen here, what did I remove in the last step? heureka" ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK: Uhmm, no actually the code is very comprehensive with some thousand lines and several includes which are dynamically included. I started reducing it, to minimize the overhead for a codeviewer but after half an hour I still have lots of stuff before me. On the other hand I can't simply send the whole thing as I have to be sure to remove all private data... I think I will drop the issue and return to the last working version - even though I am still really curious what kind of bug could cause such a symptom. I can only hope to run into it again, when rebuilding the changes...

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just an example of what I mean by "[simple, self-contained (,correct) example](http://sscce.org/)".

```
<?php
$server = setup();
$SQL = 'SELECT id,x,y,z FROM soFoo';
$Result = mysqli_query($server,$SQL);
echo '<br>'.$SQL.'*'.mysqli_num_rows($Result);
#die('test');

function setup() {
    $server = new mysqli('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly', 'test');
    if ( $server->connect_errno ) {
        die('!'.$server->connect_error);
    }

    $server->query('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFoo (
            id int auto_increment,
            x char(255),
            y char(255),
            z char(255),
            primary key(id) 
        )
    ') or die('!'.$server->error);

    $stmt=$server->prepare('INSERT INTO soFoo (x,y,z) VALUES (?,?,?)')
        or die('!'.$server->error);

    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $x, $y, $z) or die('!'.$stmt->error);
    foreach( range('a','n') as $x) { // fill in 14 records
        $z = $y = $x;
        $stmt->execute() or die('!'.$stmt->error);
    }
    return $server;
}
```

you just have to copy&paste it, adjust the MySQL connection data (credentials, host, database) and then run it.

In my case it prints `<br>SELECT id,x,y,z FROM soFoo*14` as expected (since the setup() function added 14 records to the temporary table) regardless of whether the die() was there or not. So this example doesn't behave like your description, yet it contains the information (and the code snippet) you've provided. Something must be different on your side.
I've tested the script with php5.6.10 (win32) and MySQL 5.6.22-log (win32).

Comment: Yes, I tried and it's the same here. I also created such a minimized example with my table already and this works too. I likely have a bug in my other code - but one with a behaviour which I could not even create if I wanted to. So I hoped there might be some other reason (e.g. when you wrote of buffered or unbuffered queries I got a short ray of hope... like some kind of buffering when the PHP script is forcefully killed or any other wierd explanation I could not think of) that is why I asked here.

Comment: VolkerK, I don't know whether you are still interested or whether you are informed automatically about this, but I edited my original post...

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue where to look for the error. But if you haven't already tried that a debugger might help you to pin point the error, see e.g. https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html For me developing without a working debugger is possible but futile ;-)

Comment: Having no debugger is disciplining me to make less errors - at least I like the thought of me believing that - but luckily I found the error now or at least the reason that triggers it :-)

Comment: Wooz, I am curious what triggers it - oh and using an IDE (like netbeans) is a really good idea, don't make your life harder than it needs to be

Comment: @Wee Zel: I wrote the error source in the original post as "Edit 2" or did you mean you wanted more details? And yes, things like this make me feel like reconsidering my asceticism.

Comment: I used to use vi to write code, then debug it with `var_dump()`, `print_r()` and `echo` statements. Now I use netbeans and xdebug and it's 5 times quicker, the code is higher quality and I have a better understanding of how it flows (98% of the code I maintain is not mine).